# Cannot find controller from IntelliJ Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, controller

I'm having troubles configuring spring mvc project in intelliJ (I cannot use spring boot at this project).

I cannot seem to hit my controller:

```
package app.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registerUser(Model m, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("HERE");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

as I always get 404 error when I try localhost:8080/user/registerUser.

I realized in order to have HttpServletRequest class, I either need to import last dependency in my pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.nemanjagajic</groupId>
    <artifactId>Reserve</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

or I can go File->Project Structure->Modules, choose Dependencies tab and than add library Tomcat 9.0.6, but in any case I cannot hit my controller.
The same project seems to work in Eclipse, so I guess it has something to do with configuring server aka tomcat in this case, but I struggle finding the way to configure it properly in IntelliJ.

I'll leave github repository of project if somebody wants to try it:
https://github.com/nemanjagajic/Reserve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please rename web->webapp and move in to the src->main folder.
2. Update pom.xml as below.

   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       4.0.0

   ```
   <groupId>com.nemanjagajic</groupId>
   <artifactId>Reserve</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
           <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
           <version>1.11.1.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>jstl</groupId>
           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
           <version>1.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.5</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
           <version>8.5.15</version>
           <type>pom</type>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.2</version>
               <configuration>
                   <port>8080</port>
                   <path>/</path>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
3. Update webConfig.java as below.

   ```
      @Bean
            public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
                InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new      InternalResourceViewResolver();
                resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
               resolver.setPrefix("/");
               resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
               return resolver;
        }
   ```

here is the working example.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the problem!
Since you've downloaded project and are already familiar, do you maybe know why it stops suddenly background video and shows error:
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resources/video/background-video.mp4] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'